# External deivce control and data I/O with the Nexus 5X

Tags: applications

I'm trying to understand how I might go about controlling an external LED array and then move image data off using an android device. I have identified two tasks, the first is very simple, I have a boost converter circuit which just needs to be triggered by a square pulse, all the timing thereafter is handled in hardware. I figured I could do this with the mic jack. The second task is perhaps more complicated. I would like to send images over the USB to another system for post processing.

Are there any resources or tutorials available for this type of problem? I am more than anything just looking for a place to start.